# What causes the computer to lose its time?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, time

Are there problems associated with the computer having to lose its time?
How do I solve it? The time I'm referring to is the one that is found on the lower-right corner of the screen.

Comment: "Keeping Time on the PC" http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/01/keeping-time-on-the-pc.html

Answer (score 8):

Most likely a problem with the on-board battery. But that could depend the time from and to which it resets (and could range from a virus to using a time server).

Comment: Agreed. The battery is easy to replace, though. Here's how: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000239.htm

Comment: will it have other ill effects on the system if I dont replace the battery soon?

Comment: @Ieyasu Sawada You could lose all BIOS settings, and be forced to set them by hand after each boot if the battery runs out of charge.  On some computer, settings won't be lost until you unplug it. Since it's a laptop, it could be difficult to replace the on-board battery.